# I want to increase width of Bootstrap container on Max width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to increase the width of the Bootstrap container on Max width with all devices responsive please help me how can do that  ? thanks.

**My website link here please check ** https://urbanhomesrental.com/

**css**

```
   .container.home-container {
        max-width:1476px;
}
```

**html view**

```
 <div class="container home-container">
            <div class="rounded">
            <video class="video" autoplay="" loop="" muted="">
                <source src="https://urbanhomesrental.com/castle-theme- 
          assets/video/video-slider.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: If you want the width to be larger than the default container, maybe try using `container-fluid` instead of `container`.

Comment: No sir I don't want to use container-fluid it will make more width I want to make small width, not like a container-fluid

Comment: Your question started with 'increase the width of the Bootstrap container' so I thought, so maybe edit that part. You might also want to elaborate your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

just add `!important` to your class... You can use the same bootstrap class but adding your style... You must to make sure your css file or `style` tag is after bootstrap file :)
example:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.container{
  max-width: 100vw!important;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container bg-primary">
  Hey there
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```html
<div class="container home-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="rounded">
                <video class="video" autoplay="" loop="" muted="">
                    <source src="https://urbanhomesrental.com/castle-theme-
          assets/video/video-slider.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).